# 'out of something' usage

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

I came across some sentences using out of something or someone and I can't make its meaning clear all the time, say ***I want to make a supersonic man out of you***. How can I understand this sentence and out of here represent what?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently not supersonic but I want to make you that way. This is from Queen's lyrics and the true meaning is that the singer wants to make you more that you currently are. He is full of life and wants you to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_out_of):

It simply means to create/construct X (product/result) using Y (material/substance to be processed/utilized).

> I want to make a supersonic man out of you

Supersonic Man = product/result

You = Material to be processed/utilized

You might be interested to see [this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85091/make-something-out-of-or-make-something-with/85095) in EL&U.

PS: The example sentence seems like a science experiment to me. Reminds me of Captain America and the Hulk.